# android bluetooth find devices error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using the Bluetooth chat code which was provided by [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) already. I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm wrong in the code. It suppose to call on the `DeviceList` class which a Dialog but everytime i clicked on the `Find Devices` button on actionbar. The app crashes. I have this error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` This is from my logcat. I dont know the reason why this has to be the cause of the app to crash. Please help

Logcat

```
08-23 11:34:31.237: V/ActivityThread(3440): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}} finished=false
08-23 11:34:31.238: D/ActivityThread(3440): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}}
08-23 11:34:31.238: V/ActivityThread(3440): Resume ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
08-23 11:34:31.239: V/PhoneWindow(3440): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420f5ee0 I.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
08-23 11:34:31.241: V/ViewRootImpl(3440): mApplyParallel = false, this = ViewRoot{421209e0 ,ident = 5}
08-23 11:34:31.245: V/ActivityThread(3440): Resuming ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}} with isForward=true
08-23 11:34:31.245: V/PhoneWindow(3440): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{421209e0 com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity,ident = 5}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420f5ee0 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-0,0}
08-23 11:34:31.246: V/ActivityThread(3440): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}}
08-23 11:34:31.247: D/ActivityThread(3440): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{420f26b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@420f1e90 {com.project.tsateacher/bluetooth.DeviceListActivity}}
08-23 11:34:31.265: D/ListView(3440): measureHeightOfChildren adapter=android.widget.ArrayAdapter@4211a940, startPosition=0, endPosition=5, maxHeight=776, this=android.widget.ListView{4210a4c8 VFED.VC. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090029 app:id/paired_devices}
08-23 11:34:31.267: E/ArrayAdapter(3440): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
08-23 11:34:31.275: D/AndroidRuntime(3440): Shutting down VM
08-23 11:34:31.275: D/dalvikvm(3440): threadid=1: detach (group=0x4187fce0)
08-23 11:34:31.275: W/dalvikvm(3440): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4187fce0)
08-23 11:34:31.275: W/dalvikvm(3440): threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
08-23 11:34:31.276: W/System.err(3440): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
08-23 11:34:31.282: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16875)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5394)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16875)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5394)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16875)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5394)
08-23 11:34:31.283: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16875)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5394)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2504)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16875)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2403)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1369)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1640)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6412)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
08-23 11:34:31.284: W/System.err(3440):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5334)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 11:34:31.285: W/System.err(3440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-23 11:34:31.286: W/System.err(3440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
08-23 11:34:31.286: W/System.err(3440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
08-23 11:34:31.286: W/System.err(3440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 11:34:31.287: W/System.err(3440): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
08-23 11:34:31.289: W/System.err(3440):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
08-23 11:34:31.289: W/System.err(3440):     ... 40 more
08-23 11:34:31.289: W/dalvikvm(3440): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): Process: com.project.tsateacher, PID: 3440
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2338)
08-23 11:34:31.298: E/AndroidRuntime(3440):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren
```

DeviceListActivity.java

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Return Intent extra
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the window
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_device_list);

        // Set result CANCELED in case the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
        // one for newly discovered devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.bluetooth_device_name);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.bluetooth_device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get a set of currently paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                        + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired)
                    .toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the
            // View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
    // changes the title when discovery is finished
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed
                // already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                            + device.getAddress());
                }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                    .equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(
                            R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Clicking the icon for searching devices calls the DeviceListActivty class but it crashes.

Comment: It is clear, you have to set a textview, sounds clear i think, and complete or more detailed logcat, please

Comment: can you show your ArrayAdapter Code and xml plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, since I can't see your code, but it seems caused by the way you define your arrayadpter and you need to add your Textview to adpter, for example:

```
ArrayList<String> Test_list = new ArrayList<String>();

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.AAA,R.id.test,
            Test_List);
```

The AAA.xml:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</TextView>
```

if you use:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.AAA,
            Test_List);//without the textview info (R.id.test)
```

You may get this error.